# My PHP code doesnt seem to want to connect to the database and/or display the data, can someone point out what's wrong?

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel, database

So basically I am trying to simply just connect to my local mysql database with a football table to display on the site, but it doesn't seem to be able to connect. I feel like it's really obvious but I just can't see it.. I have checked the password is correct also, and it is.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "password"
$dbname = "import_excel_to_mysql";

/* Create connection */
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "import_excel_to_mysql");
/* Check connection */
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error . mysql_error());
} 

$sql = "SELECT position, team_name, played, wins, draws, losses, goals_scored, goals_against, goal_difference, points FROM football table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Pos</th><th>Team Name</th><th>P</th><th>W</th><th>D</th><th>L</th>(etc)</tr>";
    /* output data of each row */
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $row["position"]. "</td><td>" . $row["team_name"]. " " . $row["played"]. " " . $row["wins"]. " " . $row["draws"]. (etc)"</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
?>
```

It should display the table just on its own, but instead it displays all the php code starting at `connect_error(`. The rest of the site is unaffected.

Comment: It is good practice to never include a password (or 2) in a question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sounds like PHP isn't getting run. Is this a .php file? Have you installed PHP properly and set up the web server to use it?

Comment: I agree with @Jonnix. You probably need to rename the file from `file.html` to `file.php` for it to work. Same in your browser, of course.

Comment: why do you define db deets to then not use them? also, have you checked error logs/enabled errors?

Comment: Also, `mysql_error()` won't help you when you're using mySQLi. And if you're using php7 it won't even run and will result in an error. You should remove it. You've already used `$conn->connect_error` correctly in that string, so just leave it at that.

Comment: After two days of figuring this out, i finally sorted it. Jonnix was right, PHP wasnt getting run, and i had to change the port so it ran correctly etc, and eventually it was fixed. Cheers lads